# It dont go in my loop while but its superior like the condition

Tags: reactjs, express, node-sqlite3

I call an int parameter of my DB ( here 1159 ) and if it is higher than 650, then it enters the loop and must decrement, as well as decrement a stitch counter to 10 at the beginning.

However 1159 > 650 but it skips the while loop.

See for yourself, I don't understand https://gyazo.com/0c766a40e8134b3cfec8fe50579c9d47.

```
while (price > 650){
        price -= 100
        pts_tel -= 1}
```

I tried to parseInt(price) but it changes nothing.

If you have any idea, thanks ! ( sry for my bad english )

Answer (score 0):

My price was an object, so i did price.price and it works.